# Neo4j slow saving

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am using `neo4j` version `1.8.1` and `spring-data-neo4j` version `2.2.0. RELEASE`.

The problem is about neo4j saving speed. I could not realize why this happens. The node is persisting into db for about 30 second. Here is my model class.

```
@NodeEntity
public class GraphUser {


    public static final String FACEBOOK_FRIEND = "FACEBOOK_FRIEND";
    public static final String TWITTER_FOLLOW = "TWITTER_FOLLOW";
    public static final String CONTACT = "CONTACT";
    public static final String KNOWS = "KNOWS";
    public static final String BLOCKED = "BLOCKED";
    public static final String FAVORITE = "FAVORITE";

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed(unique = true, indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "userIdIndex")
    private String userId;

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "facebookIdIndex")
    private String facebookId;

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "twitterIdIndex")
    private String twitterId;

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "emailIndex")
    private String email;

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "phoneNumberIndex")
    private String phoneNumber;

    private String knowsLevel;

    @RelatedTo(type = FACEBOOK_FRIEND, direction = Direction.BOTH)
    @Fetch
    private Set<GraphUser> facebookRelations = new HashSet<GraphUser>();

    @RelatedTo(type = TWITTER_FOLLOW, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    @Fetch
    private Set<GraphUser> twitterRelations = new HashSet<GraphUser>();

    @RelatedTo(type = CONTACT, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    @Fetch
    private Set<GraphUser> contacts = new HashSet<GraphUser>();


    @RelatedTo(type = KNOWS, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    @Fetch
    private Set<GraphUser> knows = new HashSet<GraphUser>();

    @RelatedTo(type = BLOCKED, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    @Fetch
    private Set<GraphUser> blocks = new HashSet<GraphUser>();

    @RelatedTo(type = FAVORITE, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    @Fetch
    private Set<GraphUser> favorites = new HashSet<GraphUser>();

    @Query(value = "start user=node({self}), user2=node(*), matchedUser=node(*) " +
            "where has(user2.userId) and has(matchedUser.userId) and has(user.knowsLevel) and has(user2.knowsLevel) and has(matchedUser.knowsLevel) " +
            "and " +
            "user.userId<>matchedUser.userId " +
            "and " +
            "(" +
            "(user.knowsLevel='ALL' and (matchedUser.knowsLevel='ALL' or (user)<-[:KNOWS]-(matchedUser) or ((user)<-[:KNOWS]-(user2)<-[:KNOWS]-(matchedUser) and matchedUser.knowsLevel='SECOND'))) " +
            "or " +
            "(user.knowsLevel='SECOND' and ((user)-[:KNOWS]->(matchedUser) or (user)-[:KNOWS]->(user2)-[:KNOWS]->(matchedUser)) and (matchedUser.knowsLevel='ALL' or (user)<-[:KNOWS]-(matchedUser) or ((user)<-[:KNOWS]-(user2)<-[:KNOWS]-(matchedUser) and matchedUser.knowsLevel='SECOND'))) " +
            "or " +
            "(user.knowsLevel='FIRST' and (user)-[:KNOWS]->(matchedUser) and (matchedUser.knowsLevel='ALL' or (user)<-[:KNOWS]-(matchedUser) or ((user)<-[:KNOWS]-(user2)<-[:KNOWS]-(matchedUser) and matchedUser.knowsLevel='SECOND')))" +
            ") " +
            "return matchedUser")
    @Fetch
    private Iterable<GraphUser> matchedUsers;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }


    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    public String getFacebookId() {
        return facebookId;
    }


    public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
        this.facebookId = facebookId;
    }


    public String getTwitterId() {
        return twitterId;
    }


    public void setTwitterId(String twitterId) {
        this.twitterId = twitterId;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getKnowsLevel() {
        return knowsLevel;
    }

    public void setKnowsLevel(String knowsLevel) {
        this.knowsLevel = knowsLevel;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }


    public Set<GraphUser> getFacebookRelations() {
        return facebookRelations;
    }


    public void setFacebookRelations(Set<GraphUser> facebookRelations) {
        this.facebookRelations = facebookRelations;
    }


    public Set<GraphUser> getTwitterRelations() {
        return twitterRelations;
    }


    public void setTwitterRelations(Set<GraphUser> twitterRelations) {
        this.twitterRelations = twitterRelations;
    }


    public Set<GraphUser> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }


    public void setContacts(Set<GraphUser> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }


    public Set<GraphUser> getKnows() {
        return knows;
    }


    public void setKnows(Set<GraphUser> knows) {
        this.knows = knows;
    }


    public Set<GraphUser> getBlocks() {
        return blocks;
    }


    public void setBlocks(Set<GraphUser> blocks) {
        this.blocks = blocks;
    }


    public Set<GraphUser> getFavorites() {
        return favorites;
    }


    public void setFavorites(Set<GraphUser> favorites) {
        this.favorites = favorites;
    }
}
```

What may I be missing ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two suspects

1. Indexes: I see you have around 5 indexes. Write takes longer when you have more indexes as the write should also update the index as part of the transaction.
2. Eager Fetch: I see you have around 6 relationships that you annotated with @Fetch. I believe spring-data-neo4j tries to re-fetch everything after the commit. And if these relationships/nodes have @Fetch for their own properties annotated with @Fetch then they are recursively fetched.

I suggest you start testing this by first removing @Fetch and then @Index and see if that improves performance. Are you also doing batch inserts?

Comment: I remove indexes and fetchs. But I realized that, it dislike my variable named `matchedUsers` which is retreived with custom query. I know that is big query but, why spring runs it every saving even if I removed fetch. Probably spring runs this one for every node after saving an object. How can I make spring not to run this query.

And I don't batch insert. it is one by one.

Comment: did you try removing the @Fetch on "matchedUsers"?

Comment: Yep. It is still slow and it is because of matchedUsers

Comment: @AhmetDAL Move the "matchedUers" query to Repository.

Comment: I did it. But even if there is no data in db the repository method takes much time. Probably this problem is about query optimization and I should ask it as another question.

Comment: I agree, you have way too many fetches, `@Fetch` should be used sparsely , for things you **always** need there. Otherwise use, e.g.  `template.fetch(user.blocks)` on demand. And this is not about Neo4j just loading too much stuff per request.

Comment: Are you running embedded or remote? I would also love to see some java-profiling results to see where the time is actually spent.

Comment: Did you using RestGraphDatabaseService with Neo4J, i also encountered the same obstacles. If using custom query to create node it was so fast, but my index not created.